# How to write a code example with code missing in documentation?

Tags: ruby, documentation

Right now I have the following example code in my documentation:

```
some_keeper = SomeKeeper.new
some_keeper.report
# ...
# save the report to a file
# ...
some_keeper.fix!
```

The `save the report to a file` won't be filled later on, it will just remain like that in the documentation, a "missing code" snippet.

**Is there a standard for "code missing" in documentation?**

NOTE: I am writing in Ruby and using Yardoc for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A list of available tags can be found [here](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#taglist).  There is no tag for missing, but you could add a note.  However, you can also define your own tags using define_tag.

That means you could define your own `@missing` tag.

http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#Adding_Custom_Tags

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear enough. The code I posted is a code snippet _inside_ a documentation file. The missing code part is part of an example.